# How to fix the error: Error: " Error in `vectbl_as_row_location()`:

Tags: r, error-code

Error: " Error in `vectbl_as_row_location()`:
! Can't subset rows with `r`.
✖ Logical subscript `r` must be size 1 or 48000, not 32.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred. "
[Error at the end of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDiBi.png)

Hi, I'm trying to do a random forest modeling on my data and I'm getting an attached image error, does anyone know what this error is and how to fix it? Thankful

Comment: You will usually get more help if you create a reproducible example.

Comment: What do you mean by a repeatable example?

Comment: Your example uses data that we do not have.  Create an example with a small amount of data that causes the same error, and provide the data in the example.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example